# Log to disk all queries that waited for a lock over a period of time

Tags: mariadb, logging

I manage a mariadb 10.4.17 server, and I'm having the issues with a table, it seems randomly I will get lots of queries "waiting for metadata lock" causing my entire database to be useless.

I usually have to restart my server to get the database running again.

I'm looking for methods that can consistently log to disk all the queries who can use problems, without affecting performance too much.

I like something like this

> watch -n 0.5 'mysqladmin -u root -ppassword "processlist"' > log.txt

But I don't know how to order by state. Anyway I'm open to any ideas. Looking for something I can look at to see what happened in the past because when the issue happens I just want to restart the db to get back online asap and don't have time to dig the root of the issue

Comment: I've added a db<>fiddle to my answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `long_query_time` as follows:

If you want it done permanently set it in `mysql.cnf` in the [server] section.

`long_query_time=123.123` (down to millisecond precision)

From [here](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/es/system-variables/long_query_time/) - you can also set it dynamically.

Issue the command (from the `mysql` CLI (Command Line Interface) client):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%long%'
```

or similar and set it. You can find out and/or set the destination file by issuing;

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%slow%'
```

Check out the [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a76f69842f459a40164cf36e5a864fd5)!

Comment: How is this going to log to my disk to help track the issue AFTER it happened and I restarted the db?

Comment: In a word, (well, two words), it can't! Sorry, I missed the  `past` bit of the question - that's like asking how do I close the stable door after the horse had bolted (and have the horse still inside). This is why monitoring tools are there - so you can monitor **for the rainy day** when problems occur! Backing up, monitoring and logging are the boring, mundane tasks that people avoid **but shouldn't**. Just start logging and monitoring from now. What OS are you using?

Comment: I can't sit and watch the db 24/7 and when the issue happens, I Just want to restart the db so i'm back online asap and not spend time debugging stuff..

Comment: that's why I need historical data, logged on disk

Comment: Well then, for starters, enable the slow query log (or whatever it's called)  - if your OS is Linux or similar - then use the [Sysstat suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysstat) to monitor your entire system (can't praise this tool highly enough!) and then compare normal running with when your system fails. Check out time of day, day of week and of month (don't know what your system does) and then **NEXT** time, you'll be able to perform diagnostics - but you can't look at the past without having recorded (i.e. monitored and logged) it in some way!